# Bash regex find replace

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, timestamp

I have a json file with lots of timestamps in it.  This file can contain thousands upoin thousands of timestamps.  Currently these timestamps are in the format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.microseconds (6 digits after the decimal point).

I am trying to index these into elasticsearch but I really have no idea how to get this in without converting the date format to miliseconds not microseconds.

How can I write something in bash which can search and replace all occurances of dates in the format mentioned and replace it by the same timestamp truncated to 3 digits rather than 6?  I am not really even sure where to start.

Comment: Don't use `bash` to parse JSON; use a language with a proper JSON parser available.

Comment: I would if this was something I needed to do a lot, however this is just a one off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
d2='[0-9]\{2\}'
sed -e "s=\($d2/$d2/$d2$d2 $d2:$d2:$d2\.[0-9]\{3\}\)[0-9]\{3\}=\1=g"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sed:

```
sed 's-\([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)[0-9][0-9][0-9]-\1-g' file
```

You might want to add the argument `-i` for an in-place edit (update file directly), but I'd suggest to check the results first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash.

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}\ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3} ]]; then
        echo $BASH_REMATCH
    fi
done < file
```